# How Show the time running in console?

Tags: c#, console-application, timespan

C#
I need to show the time running while the process is doing, shows the seconds increasing, normally: 00:00:01, 00:00:02, 00:00:03..... etc.

I'm using this code:

```
var stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();

//here is doing my process
stopwatch.Stop();
```

when the process stop, I show the time ELAPSED, with this:

```
TimeSpan ts = stopwatch.Elapsed;
```

...and this:

```
{0} minute(s)"+ " {1} second(s)", ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds/10.
```

this show the total time elapsed, But I need show the time running in console.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
while (true)
{
    Console.Write(stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString());
    Console.Write('\r');
}
```

---

## UPDATE

To prevent display of milliseconds:

```
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToInt32(stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds));
            Console.Write(timeSpan.ToString("c"));
            Console.Write('\r');
        }
```

Comment: ok. so how can I hide the miliseconds? only shows hour:minutes:seconds

Comment: Use `stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString("hh:mm:ss") `

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you are wanting to continually update the timespan on the console while the work is still proceeding.  Is that correct?  If so, you will need to either do the work in a separate thread, or update the console in a separate thread.  One of the best references I've seen for threading is http://www.albahari.com/threading/.

Hope this helps.